# Adding price in woocommerce total

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

In my header I already have an option that will show the number of items in my cart, that will change every time I click on add to cart button. I also have total amount, but that won't add up as I add products to cart. In my header is

```
<?php if( in_array('woocommerce/woocommerce.php', get_option('active_plugins')) ):?>
    <p id="shop_links" class="cart_right"><?php _e('Cart:','theme') ?>
        <a class="link_cart" href="<?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url(); ?>">
            <span>
            <?php 
                echo '<span class="items_count">' . $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count . '</span> ' ._n('item', 'items',  $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count ,'theme') . ' ' . '&mdash; ' . $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total() ;
            ?>
            </span>
            <i class="icon-shoppingbag"></i>
        </a>
    </p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

My button has class `.add_to_cart_ajax` and the code that works for number of items in cart is

```
$('.add_to_cart_ajax').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var product_id = $this.data('product_id');
    var added_title = $this.data('added_title');
    var $shop_links = $('#shop_links');
    var $cart_no = $shop_links.find('.link_cart span .items_count');
    var $cart_amount = $shop_links.find('.link_cart span .amount');
    var currentPrice = $this.parents('li.product').find('.price ins .amount , .price > .amount').text();
    var data = {
        action: 'theme_add_to_cart_wishlist',
        product_id: product_id,
        add_to: 'cart'
    };
    $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        $cart_no.text(parseInt($cart_no.text())+1);
        $cart_amount.text(parseFloat($cart_amount.replace(/[.,](?=.*[.,])/g, "").replace(",", ".").text())+currentPrice.replace(/[.,](?=.*[.,])/g, "").replace(",", "."));
        if(!$this.hasClass('in-cart')){
            $this.addClass('in-cart').tipsy("hide").attr("original-title",added_title).tipsy("show");
        }
    });
});
```

But the part `$cart_amount` doesn't do what I'd like it to do (add price as I click on various products). I tested with `console.log` when I click on the add to cart button I get the right price out. So what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution of sorts

```
<?php if ( $product->is_in_stock() ) : ?>
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form' ); ?>
    <form class="cart" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->id ); ?>" />
        <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button"><i class="shoppingcart"></i></button>
        <?php 
        if(in_array('yith-woocommerce-wishlist/init.php', apply_filters('active_plugins', get_option('active_plugins'))) ){
            echo do_shortcode('[yith_wcwl_add_to_wishlist]');
        }
        ?>
        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>
    </form>
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This seems to be woorking, for some reason I couldn't update the price with the ajax one. This will do.